# Handling async behavior in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I declared some functions outside of the scope of the init function, and called them in init with parameters. I've set up some console logs to track and the progress as to why I am not getting the desired outcome, even if wrong, and noticed that it completely skips the console logs within the function declarations. Moreover, I've stepped into the script using Chrome's debugger, and saw that as soon as it reaches the function declaration's head, it skips to the next line in init without stepping through the function.

My thought is this has something to do with having to use callback, but I'm not sure at this point.

I've already tested various orders, various forms of declaring the functions, between declaring them in init to nesting their declarations. All with the same results, give or take. Which leads me to think the compiler views this as something that would take more time and skips to the next line right away.

Here's the relevant portion of the code.

```
export default class Fundo extends FlexPlugin {
  constructor(PLUGIN_NAME) {
    super(PLUGIN_NAME);
    this.state = {
      token: "",
      cid: "",
    };
    this.fetchToken = this.fetchToken.bind(this);
    this.fetchCustomer = this.fetchCustomer.bind(this);
  }

  fetchToken = info => {
    const http = require("https");
    http.request(info, res => {
      var chunks = [];
      res.on("data", function(chunk) {
        chunks.push(chunk);
      });
      res.on("end", () => {
        var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
        var temp = JSON.parse(body);
        this.setState({
          token: "Token " + temp.accessToken,
        });
        console.log(this.token);
      });
    });
  };

  fetchCustomer = (info2, password) => {
    const http = require("https");
    http.request(info2, res => {
      var chunks = [];
      res.on("data", chunk => {
        chunks.push(chunk);
      });
      res.on("end", () => {
        var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
        var temp = JSON.parse(body);
        var temp2 = temp.items[0].customerId;
        this.setState({
          cid: temp2,
        });
        console.log(this.state.cid);
      });
    });
  };

  init(flex, manager) {
    const options = {
      method: "GET",
      hostname: "hostnamegoeshere.com",
      headers: {
        //api header info
      },
    };
    const options2 = {
      method: "GET",
      hostname: "api.epicloansystems.com",
      headers: {
        //moreheaderinfo
      },
    };
    this.fetchToken(options);
    this.fetchCustomer(options2, this.state.token);
    flex.CRMContainer.defaultProps.uriCallback = cid => {
      console.log("hereD");
      return `https://hostandpath.aspx?cid=${this.state.cid}`;
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: why are you rebinding class functions in the constructor? The constructor shouldn't need to know anything about which class functions exist, that is literally _why_ you already wrote a class. Just make sure to call those functions in a way that preserves `this`, which you're already doing by using arrow functions. Just fix your function signature: instead of `fetchToken = info => {` write normal `fetchToken(info) {` signatures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JavaScript, async code (e.g. making an HTTP request) is non-blocking, meaning that the callback you have provided for your async code will get executed at some point in the future. The callbacks you have provided in your `http.request` will execute asynchronously.

So basically, at the time you are calling `this.fetchCustomer`, `this.fetchToken` has not actually set the state with the token you need!

You would need something similar to

```
 // not an exact solution here but this is roughly 
 // what the setup would look like if fetchToken returned a promise

this.fetchToken(options).then(() => { this.fetchCustomer(this.state.token) });
```

Good resource for learning more about that: https://blog.bitsrc.io/understanding-asynchronous-javascript-the-event-loop-74cd408419ff

In general, this is where you would use something like a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) to control the flow of async code that depends on one another.